# Galaxy Nexus Suddenly restarts

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus

My Galaxy Nexus is suddenly restarting and I don't know why. How can I discover why this is happening?

Comment: is your nexus updated from 2.3 to 4.0?

Comment: @Padma: Galaxy Nexus ships with 4.0.

Comment: @Luiz: Can you give more details? Is the phone overheating, perhaps?

Comment: @AlEverett no it isn't overheating, It just simply restart. Sometimes it's idle and I'm not even using it and it restarts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a few reports floating around the web, including [this one from BGR](http://www.bgr.com/2012/01/16/galaxy-nexus-users-plagued-by-random-reboots/) this is a known software bug which Google is working to correct.

I get them on my GN occasionally as well and in my experience it's 100% random, so I don't think there's anything we can do to avoid them.

Comment: I received an OTA update and the phone stoped restarting